# Force orientation in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, orientation

i'm in need to force the orientation of the interface in landscape is the app runs in an iPad device.
I have found some code in stackoverflow that call

```
   let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue
    UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

in a buttons and it should force the orientation of the device but i experienced no change in my app. the set to landscaperight does absolutely nothing.
How can i achieve the rotation?

Comment: Hey Lorenzo, do you need to fix the apps orientation the whole time in landscape or just after an user input?

Comment: only in case the app is run on iPad... but i have found the problem: the settings of the project need to be "fullscreen required"... my bad